# Training Conditional DCGAN with GAN-CLS loss

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, discriminator

I am trying to implement conditional GAN using GAN-CLS loss as described in paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05396

So, while training discriminator, I should I have three batches of data:

1. [Real_Image, Embeddings]
2. [Generated_Image, Embeddings]
3. [Wrong_Image,Embeddings]

And, while training generator, I should have one batch of data i.e [Generated_Image, Embeddings].

Is this correct way to train the model?